# Python Scripting Displaying Incorrect Names after Join Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-joins, table

My problem is that the code is adding numbers to the field names, and this is incorrect.

Problem:

Field should be names VALUE_122, but after running JoinField code, it becomes VALUES_122_123. The values inside are correct.

I have manually gone over the code for the join field, and it does not contain the numbers 123 anywhere.Interestingly, VALUE_123 is not a field in anyone of the 2 tables involved in the joining.

I am using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: It's probably because you have two fields named `VALUE_122`.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it's not a problem of having [qualified field names](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/environments/qualified-field-names.htm) enabled e.g. `TableName1.FieldName1`. I suspect @Paul is right, Both tables have a field called `VALUE_122`, so when you join them, one field gets renamed something else. Field names are [validated](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/validatefieldname.htm) internally each time a new field is added in the user interface.

Comment: I agree with Paul. To elaborate, you likely have VALUE_122 in the target and source layers of your join. I have seen this many times.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the field in question appears in both the tables. Possible fix is to copy one of the fields, re-name and then delete original field. Can confirm that I was unable to find the setting for the Qualified Field Names, and it did nothing in the script.

Comment: In the menu Geoprocessing > Environment Settings > Fields is a checkbox to maintain fully qualified field names. This can also be accessed in python via arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = True.